# Determine a prime number with right fold

Tags: haskell, primes, lazy-evaluation, fold, primality-test

I found this solution on the internet and I need some help understanding it:

```
isPrime' :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime' n = foldr (\x acc -> (n `rem` x) /= 0 && acc) True primes
    where primes = 2 : filter isPrime' [3,5..]
```

A couple of things:

My understanding is that if the accumulator for a fold function is a `Boolean` it has to be set in the lambda function itself. Something like:

```
(\x acc -> if (n `rem` x /= 0) then False else acc) True primes
```

But here it is not the case.

Also, the range being used for `primes` does not have a terminating number. I know the reason this works is because of Haskell's lazy evaluation, but how exactly is that working here?

Lastly, this function does not seem like it would return the proper Boolean. A prime number is one that has no other divisors but itself and 1. So shouldnt the lambda read:

```
(\x acc -> if (n `rem` x) == 0 then False else acc) True primes
```

I am thoroughly confused. Please help me out.

Comment: ``(n `rem` x) /= 0 && acc`` is equivalent to ``if (n `rem` x) /= 0 then acc else False`` or ``if (n `rem` x) == 0 then False else acc``.

Answer (score 1):

At least for me, your code doesn't finish. It is missing the stop condition, which can be seen in a similar solution from the [wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Testing_primality#Primality_Test_and_Integer_Factorization):

```
isPrime n = n > 1 &&
              foldr (\p r -> p*p > n || ((n `rem` p) /= 0 && r)) True primes

primes = 2 : filter isPrime [3,5..]
```

Here you can see, that the condition `p*p > n` produces `True`, when there is no possible prime factor left. Because of lazy execution the right part of `||` is not evaluated and the `foldr` stops.

Comment: for you and everybody else, calling `take 100 primes` prints "[2" and loops.

Answer (score 1):

having

```
primes = [p1, p2, p3, ..., pn, ...]
```

calculating

```
isPrime' n = foldr (\x acc -> (n `rem` x) /= 0 && acc) True primes
```

is as if calculating

```
isPrime' n = rem n p1 /= 0 && (
             rem n p2 /= 0 && (
             rem n p3 /= 0 && (
             ..........
             rem n pk /= 0 && (
             ..........          ..... ))))
```

For composite `n`s this works – one of the `rem` expressions will be 0, the inequality is false, and the whole expression is false too, because `&&` is short-circuiting, lazy in its 2nd argument.

For prime `n`s this will cause a problem: none of the `rem` expressions will be 0, by definition of a prime, until we reach a prime `p_i == n` itself among the primes. But it's not there yet, as we haven't detected it as being prime yet - we're just doing it right now. *To test whether it is prime, we must know that it is prime* - clearly a bad situation.

A value will be demanded from `primes` which is not there yet. This is known as "black hole". It causes an error, and calculation aborts (or becomes stuck).

To put it differently, it is as if the definition

```
primes = 2 : filter isPrime' [3,5..]
```

were defined as

```
primes = 2 : [ n | n <- [3,5..]
                 , and [rem n p /= 0 | p <- takeWhile (< n) primes]]
```

The problem is that to stop when `n` is prime, `takeWhile (< n)` must reach a prime `p` above or equal to `n` in `primes`, but it's not there yet. "Black hole".

The famous "sieve" code gets around this problem by "transposing" the workflow,

```
primes = map head . iterate (\(x:xs)-> filter ((/=0).(`rem`x)) xs) $ [2..]
```

thus making it work while retaining its computational inefficiency (the *lesser* problem of your code), testing its candidates by too many primes needlessly (where each prime is tested by all its preceding primes instead of just those not above its square root), making it unnecessarily slow.

This is mitigated by putting a properly early stop to the testing, with

```
primes = 2 : [ n | n <- [3,5..]
                 , and [rem n p /= 0 | p <- takeWhile ((<= n).(^2)) primes]]
```

which, back in terms of your definition, is equivalent to

```
isPrime' n = p1*p1 > n || rem n p1 /= 0 && (
             p2*p2 > n || rem n p2 /= 0 && (
             p3*p3 > n || rem n p3 /= 0 && (
             ..........
             pk*pk > n || rem n pk /= 0 && (
             ..........          ..... ))))
```

You can write this down as a `foldr`-based definition now (which can be seen in another answer here).

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
(n `rem` x) /= 0
```

clearly produces a Bool result. The parameter `acc` is already a Bool value. So

```
(n `rem` x) /= 0 && acc
```

is a logical-AND of two Bool values, which clearly produces a Bool result. Where is the confusion?

The input list is infinite, consisting only of odd numbers. So long as you can produce a result after examining only a finite number of values, laziness makes everything fine.

Comment: Where is the result produced? Even if the lambda evaluates to false doesnt the fold continue?

Comment: @dopatraman The definition of `&&` is `True && x = x; False && _ = False`. So `False && acc` is `False` regardless of `acc`'s value and `acc` is not evaluated in that case (and if `acc` is not evaluated, the `fold` does not continue as the recursive call to `foldr` is the value of `acc` and thus it is only evaluated when `acc` is).

Comment: `take 2 primes` loops, yes?